# Caffe training iteration loss is -nan

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement [FCN-8s](https://gist.github.com/shelhamer/91eece041c19ff8968ee) using my own custom data. While training, from scratch, I see that my loss = -nan.

Could someone suggest what's going wrong and how can I correct this? My solver.prototxt is as follows:-

The train_val.prototxt is the same as given in the [link above](https://gist.github.com/shelhamer/91eece041c19ff8968ee). My custom images are of size 3x512x640 and labels of 1x512x640.There are 11 different types of labels.

```
net: "/home/ubuntu/CNN/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 13

test_interval: 500
display: 20
average_loss: 20
lr_policy: "fixed"

base_lr: 1e-4

momentum: 0.99

iter_size: 1
max_iter: 3000
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 200
snapshot_prefix: "train"
test_initialization: false
```

Comment: what values of loss you see before it becomes `nan`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common causes of nans during training](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962226/common-causes-of-nans-during-training)