# Common causes of nans during training of neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

I've noticed that a frequent occurrence during training is `NAN`s being introduced.

Often times it seems to be introduced by weights in inner-product/fully-connected or convolution layers blowing up.

Is this occurring because the gradient computation is blowing up? Or is it because of weight initialization (if so, why does weight initialization have this effect)? Or is it likely caused by the nature of the input data?

The overarching question here is simply: **What is the most common reason for NANs to occurring during training?** And secondly, what are some methods for combatting this (and why do they work)?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

I came across this phenomenon several times. Here are my observations:

---

#### Gradient blow up

**Reason:** large gradients throw the learning process off-track.

**What you should expect:** Looking at the runtime log, you should look at the loss values per-iteration. You'll notice that the loss starts to grow *significantly* from iteration to iteration, eventually the loss will be too large to be represented by a floating point variable and it will become `nan`.

**What can you do:** Decrease the `base_lr` (in the solver.prototxt) by an order of magnitude (at least). If you have several loss layers, you should inspect the log to see which layer is responsible for the gradient blow up and decrease the `loss_weight` (in train_val.prototxt) for that specific layer, instead of the general `base_lr`.

---

#### Bad learning rate policy and params

**Reason:** caffe fails to compute a valid learning rate and gets `'inf'` or `'nan'` instead, this invalid rate multiplies all updates and thus invalidating all parameters.

**What you should expect:** Looking at the runtime log, you should see that the learning rate itself becomes `'nan'`, for example:

> ```
> ... sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 0, lr = -nan
> ```

**What can you do:** fix all parameters affecting the learning rate in your `'solver.prototxt'` file.
For instance, if you use `lr_policy: "poly"` and you forget to define `max_iter` parameter, you'll end up with  `lr = nan`...
For more information about learning rate in caffe, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30033096/1714410).

---

#### Faulty Loss function

**Reason:** Sometimes the computations of the loss in the loss layers causes `nan`s to appear. For example, Feeding [`InfogainLoss` layer with non-normalized values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27645934/1714410), using custom loss layer with bugs, etc.

**What you should expect:** Looking at the runtime log you probably won't notice anything unusual: loss is decreasing gradually, and all of a sudden a `nan` appears.

**What can you do:** See if you can reproduce the error, add printout to the loss layer and debug the error.

For example: Once I used a loss that normalized the penalty by the frequency of label occurrence in a batch. It just so happened that if one of the training labels did not appear in the batch at all - the loss computed produced `nan`s. In that case, working with large enough batches (with respect to the number of labels in the set) was enough to avoid this error.

---

#### Faulty input

**Reason:** you have an input with `nan` in it!

**What you should expect:** once the learning process "hits" this faulty input - output becomes `nan`. Looking at the runtime log you probably won't notice anything unusual: loss is decreasing gradually, and all of a sudden a `nan` appears.

**What can you do:** re-build your input datasets (lmdb/leveldn/hdf5...) make sure you do not have bad image files in your training/validation set. For debug you can build a simple net that read the input layer, has a dummy loss on top of it and runs through all the inputs: if one of them is faulty, this dummy net should also produce `nan`.

---

#### stride larger than kernel size in `"Pooling"` layer

For some reason, choosing `stride` > `kernel_size` for pooling may results with `nan`s. For example:

```
layer {
  name: "faulty_pooling"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "x"
  top: "y"
  pooling_param {
    pool: AVE
    stride: 5
    kernel: 3
  }
}
```

results with `nan`s in `y`.

---

#### Instabilities in `"BatchNorm"`

It was reported that under some settings `"BatchNorm"` layer may output `nan`s due to numerical instabilities.
This [issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/5136) was raised in bvlc/caffe and [PR #5136](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/5136) is attempting to fix it.

---

Recently, I became aware of [`debug_info`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L86-L88) flag: setting `debug_info: true` in `'solver.prototxt'` will make caffe print to log more debug information (including gradient magnitudes and activation values) during training: This information can [help in spotting gradient blowups and other problems in the training process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40510706/1714410).

Comment: Thanks, how does one interpret those numbers? What are these numbers? http://pastebin.com/DLYgXK5v
why is there only one number per layer output!? 
how should those numbers look like so that someone knows there is a problem or there is not any!?

Comment: @Hossein this is exactly what [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510706/how-to-interpret-caffe-log-with-debug-info) is all about.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am getting NAN loss for an image segmentation application trained with DICE loss (even after adding a small epsilon/ smoothness constant). My dataset contains some images whose corresponding ground-truth that do not contain any foreground label and when I removed these images from training, the loss was stabilized. I am not sure why is that?

Comment: @samrairshad have you tried increasing the epsilon in the DICE loss?

Comment: Yes I did. I opened the post at stack-overflow and pasted the loss evolution for some epochs. Here's the reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259112/dice-loss-becomes-nan-after-some-epochs?noredirect=1#comment110115202_62259112

Comment: Math intuition explained here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/326029

Answer (score 6):

In my case, not setting the bias in the convolution/deconvolution layers was the cause.

**Solution:** add the following to the convolution layer parameters.

```
bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
```

Comment: how would that look in matconvnet? I've something like 'biases'.init_bias*ones(1,4,single)

Answer (score 4):

This answer is not about a cause for `nan`s, but rather proposes a way to help debug it. 
You can have this python layer:

```py
class checkFiniteLayer(caffe.Layer):
  def setup(self, bottom, top):
    self.prefix = self.param_str
  def reshape(self, bottom, top):
    pass
  def forward(self, bottom, top):
    for i in xrange(len(bottom)):
      isbad = np.sum(1-np.isfinite(bottom[i].data[...]))
      if isbad>0:
        raise Exception("checkFiniteLayer: %s forward pass bottom %d has %.2f%% non-finite elements" %
                        (self.prefix,i,100*float(isbad)/bottom[i].count))
  def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
    for i in xrange(len(top)):
      if not propagate_down[i]:
        continue
      isf = np.sum(1-np.isfinite(top[i].diff[...]))
        if isf>0:
          raise Exception("checkFiniteLayer: %s backward pass top %d has %.2f%% non-finite elements" %
                          (self.prefix,i,100*float(isf)/top[i].count))
```

Adding this layer into your `train_val.prototxt` at certain points you suspect may cause trouble:

```
layer {
  type: "Python"
  name: "check_loss"
  bottom: "fc2"
  top: "fc2"  # "in-place" layer
  python_param {
    module: "/path/to/python/file/check_finite_layer.py" # must be in $PYTHONPATH
    layer: "checkFiniteLayer"
    param_str: "prefix-check_loss" # string for printouts
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One more solution for anyone stuck like I just was-

I was receiving nan or inf losses on a network I setup with float16 dtype across the layers and input data.  After all else failed, it occurred to me to switch back to float32, and the nan losses were solved!

So bottom line, if you switched dtype to float16, change it back to float32.

Answer (score 2):

learning_rate is high and should be decreased
The accuracy in the RNN code was nan, with select the low value for learning rate it fixes

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to build a sparse autoencoder and had several layers in it to induce sparsity. While running my net, I encountered the NaN's. On removing some of the layers (in my case, I actually had to remove 1), I found that the NaN's disappeared. So, I guess too much sparsity may lead to NaN's as well (some 0/0 computations may have been invoked!?)

Comment: can you be a little more specific? can you provide details on the configuration that had `nan`s and the fixed configuration? what type of layers? what parameters?

Comment: @shai I had used several InnerProduct (lr_mult 1, decay_mult 1, lr_mult 2, decay_mult 0, xavier, std: 0.01) layers each followed by ReLU (except the last one). I was working with MNIST, and if I remember correctly, the architecture was 784 -> 1000 -> 500 -> 250 -> 100 -> 30 (and a symmetric decoder phase); removing the 30 layer alongwith its ReLU made the NaN's disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is a very common problem with neural networks, specifically with RNN.

If your model is CNN or any other NN, please continue reading the wonderful and detailed explanation by @shai and @desertnaut in the same page.

However, if the error is related to LSTM specifically, continue here.

1. First things first, check if your input has nan or np.inf values. usually, this is not the case, but make sure these are not present.
2. The most probable reason is that you are using relu as an activation function. LSTM's or RNN in general for that matter, don't work well with relu. Read here for further explanation: [Problems of relu](https://analyticsindiamag.com/can-relu-cause-exploding-gradients-if-applied-to-solve-vanishing-gradients/).
3. So the solution for the exploding gradient problem you are encountering can be switching to tanh from relu, which is the default in LSTM's.
4. You can also try reducing the learning rate which minimizes the exploding gradients.
5. One last thing you can also do if you are bent on using relu, is using clipping_values, so that the gradients do not explode while backpropagation (reduce the value of clipvalue in your case). You can also try using droupout, but it will not be very helpful compared to the other suggestions.

Hope this helps and best of luck :)