# Keras Neural Nets, How to remove NaN values in output?

Tags: python, floating-point, neural-network, keras

I keep getting a few NaN outputs from my neural network using Keras.  I only get about one NaN per 10,000 results.  Originally I had a relu activation layer feeding into the final softmax layer.  This produced more NaN results.  I changed the activation function for the last two dense layers in the constitutional network from relu to sigmoid.  This made the problem better but I still get NaN.  Any advice for how I can completely eliminate Nan?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer((1, IMG_H, IMG_W)))

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(categories, activation = 'softmax'))
```

Comment: NaNs in your output/losses are always a very bad sign. Did you preprocess / normalize your input? Is your learning-rate small enough? NaNs should never occur if data is preprocessed correctly. [This](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/) might help.

Comment: I normalized my input between 1 and 0.  I used a small learning rate of between 0.01 and 0.001.  Right now I am adding weight regularization to see if that helps.

Comment: Normalizing between 0-1 is not necessarily what you want. This sounds like MinMax-scaler in sklearn. You want normalizing the mean and variances aka StandardScaler in sklearn. This is very important when using SGD-based algorithms! In your case the mean will be >> 0.0 and i think you didn't change the variance.

Comment: I dug through my dataset of 80k images after I realized the NaNs were always coming from the same images.  Turns out those images were solid black which is an error on part of the data provider.  When I tried to normalize them this made it blow up.

Comment: Looks like you've solved the problem, but for future reference there is a [nice question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33980220/1397061) which among other things recommends checking whether you have nan inputs.

Comment: If you post an answer to your question and accept it, it will stop showing up as unanswered in search.