# what does it mean?coffemodel values are ffff or ff7f

Tags: caffe

I have trained AlexNet for my own data (gray level medical images with size 227*227). Now that I look into the caffemodel files, I see that except some lines in the beginning all the other values are `ff7f` or `ffff` like this:

[image]

additionally when I try to visualize the network weights by python, I get this waring:
`UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.`
and nothing is shown in the figure!

Do you know what those `ff7f` or `ffff` values in my coffemodel are? why they are resulted? or any recommendation or any similar issues that have been disussed? please help me find out.

Comment: Those are possibly little-endian encodings of "not a number" (NaN) values of 32-bit floats; `7fffffff` if you'd properly group and order it.

Comment: @Rhymoid would you please explain more? how can I group pr order it?

Comment: In your screenshot, the nybbles of the floating point values are grouped and ordered as `6745 2301 6745 2301`. You should read them in the order and grouping `01234567 01234567` if you want to interpret the data yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common causes of nans during training](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962226/common-causes-of-nans-during-training)