# caffe loss is nan or 0

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I am training a network and I have changed to learning rate from 0.1 to 0.00001. The output always remains the same. No mean is used for training.
What could be the reasons for such a weird loss?

```
I1107 15:07:28.381621 12333 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: loss = 3.37134e+11 (* 1 = 3.37134e+11 loss)
I1107 15:07:28.549142 12333 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 0, loss = 1.28092e+11
I1107 15:07:28.549201 12333 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 1.28092e+11 (* 1 = 1.28092e+11 loss)
I1107 15:07:28.549211 12333 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 0, lr = 1e-07
I1107 15:07:59.490077 12333 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 50, loss = -nan
I1107 15:07:59.490170 12333 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0 (* 1 = 0 loss)
I1107 15:07:59.490176 12333 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 50, lr = 1e-07
I1107 15:08:29.177093 12333 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 100, loss = -nan
I1107 15:08:29.177119 12333 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0 (* 1 = 0 loss)
I1107 15:08:29.177125 12333 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 100, lr = 1e-07
I1107 15:08:59.758381 12333 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 150, loss = -nan
I1107 15:08:59.758513 12333 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0 (* 1 = 0 loss)
I1107 15:08:59.758545 12333 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 150, lr = 1e-07
I1107 15:09:30.210208 12333 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 200, loss = -nan
I1107 15:09:30.210304 12333 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0 (* 1 = 0 loss)
I1107 15:09:30.210310 12333 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 200, lr = 1e-07
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common causes of nans during training](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962226/common-causes-of-nans-during-training)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you loss is not `0`, not even close. You start with `3.3e+11` (that is ~10^11) and it seems like soon after it explodes and you get `nan`. You need to drastically scale down you loss values. If you are using `"EuclideanLoss"` you might want to average the loss by the size of the depth map, scale the predicted values to `[-1,1]` range, or any other scaling method that will prevent your loss from exploding.

Comment: How do you average the loss by the size of the depth map?

Comment: if you depth map size is fixed you can use `loss_weight`. otherwise, it might be more tricky.