# How to interpret caffe log with debug_info?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

When facing difficulties during training ([`nan`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33980220/1714410), [loss does not converge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41234297/1714410), etc.) it is sometimes useful to look at more verbose training log by setting [`debug_info: true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33980220/1714410) in the `'solver.prototxt'` file.

The training log then looks something like:

> ```
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer data, top blob data data: 0.343971    
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer conv1, top blob conv1 data: 0.0645037
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer conv1, param blob 0 data: 0.00899114
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer conv1, param blob 1 data: 0
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer relu1, top blob conv1 data: 0.0337982
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer conv2, top blob conv2 data: 0.0249297
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer conv2, param blob 0 data: 0.00875855
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer conv2, param blob 1 data: 0
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer relu2, top blob conv2 data: 0.0128249
> . 
> .
> .
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer fc1, top blob fc1 data: 0.00728743
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer fc1, param blob 0 data: 0.00876866
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer fc1, param blob 1 data: 0
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer loss, top blob loss data: 2031.85
> I1109 ...]     [Backward] Layer loss, bottom blob fc1 diff: 0.124506
> I1109 ...]     [Backward] Layer fc1, bottom blob conv6 diff: 0.00107067
> I1109 ...]     [Backward] Layer fc1, param blob 0 diff: 0.483772
> I1109 ...]     [Backward] Layer fc1, param blob 1 diff: 4079.72
> .
> .
> .
> I1109 ...]     [Backward] Layer conv2, bottom blob conv1 diff: 5.99449e-06
> I1109 ...]     [Backward] Layer conv2, param blob 0 diff: 0.00661093
> I1109 ...]     [Backward] Layer conv2, param blob 1 diff: 0.10995
> I1109 ...]     [Backward] Layer relu1, bottom blob conv1 diff: 2.87345e-06
> I1109 ...]     [Backward] Layer conv1, param blob 0 diff: 0.0220984
> I1109 ...]     [Backward] Layer conv1, param blob 1 diff: 0.0429201
> E1109 ...]     [Backward] All net params (data, diff): L1 norm = (2711.42, 7086.66); L2 norm = (6.11659, 4085.07)
> ```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At first glance you can see this log section divided into two: `[Forward]` and `[Backward]`. Recall that neural network training is done via forward-backward propagation:
A training example (batch) is fed to the net and a forward pass outputs the current prediction.
Based on this prediction a loss is computed.
The loss is then derived, and a gradient is estimated and propagated backward using the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

**Caffe [`Blob`](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html) data structure**
Just a quick re-cap. Caffe uses `Blob` data structure to store data/weights/parameters etc. For this discussion it is important to note that `Blob` has two "parts": `data` and `diff`. The values of the `Blob` are stored in the `data` part. The `diff` part is used to store element-wise gradients for the backpropagation step.

**Forward pass**

You will see all the layers from bottom to top listed in this part of the log. For each layer you'll see:

> ```
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer conv1, top blob conv1 data: 0.0645037
> ```

```
I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer conv1, param blob 0 data: 0.00899114
I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer conv1, param blob 1 data: 0
```

Layer `"conv1"` is a convolution layer that has 2 param blobs: the filters and the bias. Consequently, the log has three lines. The filter blob (`param blob 0`) has `data`

> ```
>  I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer conv1, param blob 0 data: 0.00899114
> ```

That is the current L2 norm of the convolution filter weights is 0.00899.
The current bias (`param blob 1`):

> ```
>  I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer conv1, param blob 1 data: 0
> ```

meaning that currently the bias is set to 0.

Last but not least, `"conv1"` layer has an output, `"top"` named `"conv1"` (how original...). The L2 norm of the output is

> ```
>  I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer conv1, top blob conv1 data: 0.0645037
> ```

Note that all L2 values for the `[Forward]` pass are reported on the `data` part of the  Blobs in question.

**Loss and gradient**
At the end of the `[Forward]` pass comes the loss layer:

> ```
> I1109 ...]     [Forward] Layer loss, top blob loss data: 2031.85
> ```

```
I1109 ...]     [Backward] Layer loss, bottom blob fc1 diff: 0.124506
```

In this example the batch loss is 2031.85, the gradient of the loss w.r.t. `fc1` is computed and passed to **`diff`** part of `fc1` Blob. The L2 magnitude of the gradient is 0.1245.

**Backward pass**
All the rest of the layers are listed in this part top to bottom. You can see that the L2 magnitudes reported now are of the `diff` part of the Blobs (params and layers' inputs).

**Finally**
The last log line of this iteration:

> ```
> [Backward] All net params (data, diff): L1 norm = (2711.42, 7086.66); L2 norm = (6.11659, 4085.07)
> ```

reports the total L1 and L2 magnitudes of both data and gradients.

**What should I look for?**

1. If you have [`nan`s in your loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962226/common-causes-of-nans-during-training?noredirect=1&lq=1), see at what point your data or diff turns into `nan`: at which layer? at which iteration?
2. Look at the gradient magnitude, they should be reasonable. IF you are starting to see values with `e+8` your data/gradients are starting to blow up. Decrease your learning rate!
3. See that the `diff`s are not zero. Zero diffs mean no gradients = no updates = no learning. If you started from random weights, consider generating random weights with higher variance.
4. Look for activations (rather than gradients) going to zero. If you are using [`"ReLU"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/relu.html) this means your inputs/weights lead you to regions where the ReLU gates are "not active" leading to ["dead neurons"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks). Consider normalizing your inputs to have zero mean, add [`"BatchNorm"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/batchnorm.html) layers, setting `negative_slope` in ReLU.

Comment: What would you change if diffs are zero?

Comment: @thigi it depends on the architecture: for instance, if you are using `ReLU` activations and the input `data` is zero - the gradient will be zero. Then you might consider changing the "working point" by e.g., subtracting mean. Alternatively, you can replace `ReLU` with `PReLU`...

Comment: @Shai: Why is L1/L2 norm is used here?

Comment: @Hossein what else should caffe report?

Comment: @Shai:  I have no idea!, I'm not coming from a AI/ML background, and thus alot of things  dont make sense to me. thats why I ask (newbish?)questions like these

Comment: @Hossein well, L1 represent the sum of absolute values of the parameters, while L2 is the sum of square values. L2 represents the "energy" of the weights. Both quantities represent the "magnitude" of the weights.

Comment: @Shai: are you sure with what you mentioned in the answer part in that "IF you are starting to see values with e+8 your data/gradients are starting to blow off."? (I mean regarding "e+8"). In my case I got something on the other extreme for the loss like 1.47348e-08 i.e. e- instead of e+.

Comment: `e-8` means something in the order of `0.00000001`: your gradients are vanishing, not exploding

Comment: @Shai: Thanks. If the gradient is vanishing, it's not learning either, right? What can I do about it? I think decreasing the learning rate is not helpful. What do you think? Perhaps, the training set is not having a high variance (not diverse enough) ?

Comment: what are 'bottom blob diff'? blobs are updated during feedforward step, diffs are derivatives wrt to weights. Is it the ds/dw term in the product of partial derivatives dE/dw = dE/dy *dy/ds *ds/dw?

Comment: @alfa_80 is the gradients vanishing for all layers?

Comment: @Shai: Yes, for all layers. But it's resolved, by now.

Comment: @Shai: FYI, I was having that vanishing gradients before because I didn't use any pre-trained model trained on my data that would need lots of fine-tuning effort if I need to get it work. After using pre-trained model, the issue was resolved.

Comment: @alfa_80 FYI, are you using `"ReLU"` activations? you may get zero gradients if most of your outputs are in the negative part of the `"ReLU"` - there is no gradient there. Using `"PReLU"` or "leaky" `"ReLU"` may resolve this issue.

Comment: @Shai: Yes, I had employed ReLU activations as well before but still problematic. Not yet tried with "PReLU" or "leaky" "ReLU" though, but it's a good point.

Comment: @alfa_80 you might also want to look into [`SELU`](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02515) activation.

Comment: @Shai: Thanks Shai. I have actually resolved the issue by using the pre-trained model for that kind of problem. But your point might be useful for others though.

Comment: @Shai Can we set debug info during the TEST only? Also, is it possible to get per layer tensor output?

Comment: @algoProg afaik the debug_info flag is global and cannot be changed between train and test phase. You can use Python interface for debugging, look at "net surgery" example for more details

Comment: @Shai Thanks for immediate reply. I asked the wrong question. I want to print out the layer outputs during the Classification. Is it possible? `debug_info` prints weights and biases, but not layer outputs themselves, and it cannot be set during the classification if I understand right.

Comment: @algoProg do you mean you want to see the actual vector of class probabilities during test?

Comment: @Shai I want to print the "top" of the Blob (which I think is the output of each layer) during the classification. Specifically, looking at the cpp_classification (classification.cpp) example in Caffe, I want to print output vector of each layer (and not the features -- weights and biases, etc.). I do not want to mess with the Train/Test sequence, as I deal with the PreTrained model. So yes, for the last layer that would be the class probability vector, but that is not difficult as Classification yields that for me. But what about intermediate layers (Conv, etc.)? Is there an API for this?

Comment: @algoProg do it in Python look at "net surgery" tutorial. if you have further questions, please post them as questions and not as comments