# How to prevent weight update in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, batch-normalization

Some layers of my net load a pretrained model. I want to fix their parameters and train other layers.

I followed [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610723/how-do-i-to-prevent-backward-computation-in-specific-layers-in-caffe)  and set `lr_multi` `decay_multi` to  0, `propagate_down: false`, and even `base_lr: 0` `weight_decay: 0` in the solver. However, the test loss (use all test images for each test) is still changing very slowly in each iter. After thousands iters the accuracy would go to 0 (from 80% when the pre-trained model was loaded).

Here is a a two-layer example which I just initialize the weights and set above parameters to 0. I want to feeze all layers in this example but when training start, the loss keeps changing...

```
  layer {
    name: "data"
    type: "ImageData"
    top: "data"
    top: "label"
    include {
      phase: TRAIN
    }
    transform_param {
      scale: 0.017
      mirror: true
      crop_size: 32
      mean_value: 115
      mean_value: 126
      mean_value: 130
      color: true
      contrast: true
      brightness: true
    }
    image_data_param {
      source: "/data/zhuhao5/data/cifar100/cifar100_train_replicate.txt"
      batch_size: 64
      shuffle: true
      #pair_size: 3
    }
  }
  layer {
    name: "data"
    type: "ImageData"
    top: "data"
    top: "label"
    include {
      phase: TEST
    }
    transform_param {
      scale: 0.017
      mirror: false
      crop_size: 32
      mean_value: 115
      mean_value: 126
      mean_value: 130
    }
    image_data_param {
      source: "/data/zhuhao5/data/cifar100/cifar100_test.txt"
      batch_size: 100
      shuffle: false
    }
  }
  #-------------- TEACHER --------------------
  layer {
    name: "conv1"
    type: "Convolution"
    bottom: "data"
    propagate_down: false
    top: "conv1"
    param { 
      lr_mult: 0 
      decay_mult: 0 
    }
    convolution_param {
      num_output: 16
      bias_term: false
      pad: 1
      kernel_size: 3
      stride: 1
      weight_filler {
        type: "msra"
      }
    }
  }
  layer {
    name: "res2_1a_1_bn"
    type: "BatchNorm"
    bottom: "conv1"
    propagate_down: false
    top: "res2_1a_1_bn"
    param { 
      lr_mult: 0 
      decay_mult: 0 
    }
        param { 
      lr_mult: 0 
      decay_mult: 0 
    }
  }
  layer {
    name: "res2_1a_1_scale"
    type: "Scale"
    bottom: "res2_1a_1_bn"
    propagate_down: false
    top: "res2_1a_1_bn"
      param { 
      lr_mult: 0 
      decay_mult: 0 
    }
    scale_param {
      bias_term: true
    }
  }
  layer {
    name: "res2_1a_1_relu"
    type: "ReLU"
    bottom: "res2_1a_1_bn"
    propagate_down: false
    top: "res2_1a_1_bn"
  }
  layer {
    name: "pool_5"
    type: "Pooling"
    bottom: "res2_1a_1_bn"
    propagate_down: false
    top: "pool_5"
    pooling_param {
      pool: AVE
      global_pooling: true
    }
  }
  layer {
    name: "fc100"
    type: "InnerProduct"
    bottom: "pool_5"
    propagate_down: false
    top: "fc100"
    param {
      lr_mult: 0
      decay_mult: 0
    }
    param {
      lr_mult: 0
      decay_mult: 0
    }
    inner_product_param {
      num_output: 100
      weight_filler {
        type: "msra"
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant"
        value: 0
      }
    }
  }
  #---------------------------------
  layer {
    name: "tea_soft_loss"
    type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
    bottom: "fc100"
    bottom: "label"
    propagate_down: false
    propagate_down: false
    top: "tea_soft_loss"
    loss_weight: 0
  }

  ##----------- ACCURACY----------------

  layer {
    name: "teacher_accuracy"
    type: "Accuracy"
    bottom: "fc100"
    bottom: "label"
    top: "teacher_accuracy"
    accuracy_param {
      top_k: 1
    }
  }
```

Here is the solver:

```
test_iter: 100

test_interval: 10

base_lr: 0
momentum: 0
weight_decay: 0

lr_policy: "poly"
power: 1

display: 10000

max_iter: 80000

snapshot: 5000

type: "SGD"

solver_mode: GPU

random_seed: 10086
```

and log:

```
I0829 16:31:39.363433 14986 net.cpp:200] teacher_accuracy does not need backward computation.
I0829 16:31:39.363438 14986 net.cpp:200] tea_soft_loss does not need backward computation.
I0829 16:31:39.363442 14986 net.cpp:200] fc100_fc100_0_split does not need backward computation.
I0829 16:31:39.363446 14986 net.cpp:200] fc100 does not need backward computation.
I0829 16:31:39.363451 14986 net.cpp:200] pool_5 does not need backward computation.
I0829 16:31:39.363454 14986 net.cpp:200] res2_1a_1_relu does not need backward computation.
I0829 16:31:39.363458 14986 net.cpp:200] res2_1a_1_scale does not need backward computation.
I0829 16:31:39.363462 14986 net.cpp:200] res2_1a_1_bn does not need backward computation.
I0829 16:31:39.363466 14986 net.cpp:200] conv1 does not need backward computation.
I0829 16:31:39.363471 14986 net.cpp:200] label_data_1_split does not need backward computation.
I0829 16:31:39.363485 14986 net.cpp:200] data does not need backward computation.
I0829 16:31:39.363490 14986 net.cpp:242] This network produces output tea_soft_loss
I0829 16:31:39.363494 14986 net.cpp:242] This network produces output teacher_accuracy
I0829 16:31:39.363507 14986 net.cpp:255] Network initialization done.
I0829 16:31:39.363559 14986 solver.cpp:56] Solver scaffolding done.
I0829 16:31:39.363852 14986 caffe.cpp:248] Starting Optimization
I0829 16:31:39.363862 14986 solver.cpp:272] Solving WRN_22_12_to_WRN_18_4_v5_net
I0829 16:31:39.363865 14986 solver.cpp:273] Learning Rate Policy: poly
I0829 16:31:39.365981 14986 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 0, Testing net (#0)
I0829 16:31:39.366190 14986 blocking_queue.cpp:49] Waiting for data
I0829 16:31:39.742347 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: tea_soft_loss = 85.9064
I0829 16:31:39.742437 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: teacher_accuracy = 0.0113
I0829 16:31:39.749806 14986 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 0 (0 iter/s, 0.385886s/10000 iters), loss = 0
I0829 16:31:39.749862 14986 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: tea_soft_loss = 4.97483
I0829 16:31:39.749877 14986 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #1: teacher_accuracy = 0
I0829 16:31:39.749908 14986 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 0, lr = 0
I0829 16:31:39.794306 14986 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 10, Testing net (#0)
I0829 16:31:40.171447 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: tea_soft_loss = 4.9119
I0829 16:31:40.171510 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: teacher_accuracy = 0.0115
I0829 16:31:40.219133 14986 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 20, Testing net (#0)
I0829 16:31:40.596911 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: tea_soft_loss = 4.91862
I0829 16:31:40.596971 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: teacher_accuracy = 0.0116
I0829 16:31:40.645246 14986 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 30, Testing net (#0)
I0829 16:31:41.021711 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: tea_soft_loss = 4.92105
I0829 16:31:41.021772 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: teacher_accuracy = 0.0117
I0829 16:31:41.069464 14986 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 40, Testing net (#0)
I0829 16:31:41.447345 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: tea_soft_loss = 4.91916
I0829 16:31:41.447407 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: teacher_accuracy = 0.0117
I0829 16:31:41.495157 14986 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 50, Testing net (#0)
I0829 16:31:41.905607 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: tea_soft_loss = 4.9208
I0829 16:31:41.905654 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: teacher_accuracy = 0.0117
I0829 16:31:41.952659 14986 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 60, Testing net (#0)
I0829 16:31:42.327942 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: tea_soft_loss = 4.91936
I0829 16:31:42.328025 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: teacher_accuracy = 0.0117
I0829 16:31:42.374279 14986 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 70, Testing net (#0)
I0829 16:31:42.761359 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: tea_soft_loss = 4.91859
I0829 16:31:42.761430 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: teacher_accuracy = 0.0117
I0829 16:31:42.807821 14986 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 80, Testing net (#0)
I0829 16:31:43.232321 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: tea_soft_loss = 4.91668
I0829 16:31:43.232398 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: teacher_accuracy = 0.0117
I0829 16:31:43.266436 14986 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 90, Testing net (#0)
I0829 16:31:43.514633 14986 blocking_queue.cpp:49] Waiting for data
I0829 16:31:43.638617 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: tea_soft_loss = 4.91836
I0829 16:31:43.638684 14986 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: teacher_accuracy = 0.0117
I0829 16:31:43.685451 14986 solver.cpp:330] Iteration 100, Testing net (#0)
```

I wonder what I missed in the updating process in caffe :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the reason.

`BatchNorm` layer use different `use_global_stats` in TRAIN and TEST phases.

In my issue, I should set `use_global_stats: true` in the training process.

And also don't forget the `Scale` layer.

The revised layers should be

```
layer {
  name: "res2_1a_1_bn"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "res2_1a_1_bn"
  batch_norm_param {
      use_global_stats: true
  }
}
layer {
  name: "res2_1a_1_scale"
  type: "Scale"
  bottom: "res2_1a_1_bn"
  top: "res2_1a_1_bn"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  scale_param {
    bias_term: true
  }
}
```