# Freezing weights in VGG19 network for transfer-learning in Caffe

Tags: caffe, vgg-net, transfer-learning, faster-rcnn

The reason why I am asking this question is due to the fact that in VGG19 there are batch-normalization layers (unlike VGG16, for example).

I am trying to train a Faster-RCNN network in Caffe. I am doing it by:

- Downloading a VGG19 ImageNet pretrained model (weights + prototxt file)
- Removing the fully-connected layers from the prototxt file
- Adding the RPN and the Fast-RCNN layers on top of the VGG19 backbone convolutional layers

I did not change anything regarding the `lr_mult` values of the convolutional layers. In the prototxt file, the convolutional layers (like `conv1_1`, etc. have non-zero `lr_mult` values, while the batch normalization layers' `lr_mult` values are set to 0 (layers named like `conv1_1/bn`).

Does the fact that the batch normalization layers are frozen means that the convolutional layers are frozen as well? Or should I set `lr_mult` to 0 also in the layers named `convX_X`?

---

**Update**: After running another training process while zeroing the `lr_mult` of all the convolutional layers, the training time reduced dramatically, which implies that the answer is that the `lr_mult` value needs to be set to 0 also in the `convX_X` layers.

Comment: do u have ur weights + prototxt file available to download?

Answer (score 2):

To properly freeze convolutional layers with batchnorm in Caffe, you should:

- For convolutional layers: Set `lr_mult` param to 0
- For batchnorm layers: Set `lr_mult` params to 0, set `use_global_stats` to `true`:

```
layer {
  name: "bn1"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "bn1"
  batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: true
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
}
```

> Does the fact that the batch normalization layers are frozen means that the convolutional layers are frozen as well?

Of course not. However, by using `propagate_down` param you can achieve this effect: [How do I to prevent backward computation in specific layers in caffe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610723/how-do-i-to-prevent-backward-computation-in-specific-layers-in-caffe).