# caffe training loss does not converge

Tags: caffe, loss

I'm getting the problem of non-converged training loss. (batchsize: 16, average loss:10).
I have tried with the following methods
   + Vary the learning rate lr (initial lr = 0.002 cause very high loss, around e+10). Then with lr = e-6, the loss seem to small but do not converge.
   + Add initialization for bias
   + Add regularization for bias and weight

This is the [network structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL9J2.png)  and the [training loss log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CUoF.png)

Hope to hear from you
Best regards

Comment: try learning rate between 0 002 and e-6

Comment: I have tried with different learning rate values such as 2e-3, 2e-4,2e-5. Those values caused very high loss (e+21).

Comment: You need to debug your training process. set `debug_info: true` in your `'solver.prototxt'` and use [these guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40510706/1714410) to see what is interfering with the training.

Comment: Thank Shai for the suggestion