# caffe, training non-image data, constant loss and accuracy

Tags: python, caffe, lmdb

I have created my own `lmdb` database consist of (non-image) 2D `numpy` lists values of data varies between 0 to `MAX_INT`.

sample size is `1500*75`, and the original is `15000*77` ( very slow to train).
 I have 2400 samples divided 5/6 for training and 1/6 testing. my net include 2 classes only (0,1).

The network isn't learning at all,  I keep getting the same values over and over again, loss is either 0 or 87.3366 and accuracy is always 0.495  from `iter 0` until `iter 20K`.

I've tried every possible solution, adjusting parameters, deepening the network, changing the whole network ! what am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `debug_info: true`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40510706/1714410

Comment: I followed your notes  about things i should be looking for, none of them is there, non nan's no values less than e+8 , and no  zero gradient, yet it's not learning !

Comment: It is very difficult from your description to understand and figure out what exactly is wrong. Have you tried [Batch Normalization](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41269570/1714410)?

Comment: It's not working either, I created a simpler version of my dataset, trying to figure out, where the error is, and i noticed that the learning  behavior is exactly the same ! noting that the fake data is supposed to be very straight forward to learn, any ideas of what the reason might be ? i used this code to create my lmdb file: http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216766/strange-training-behavior-of-nn-using-caffe