# How can I save the probability of the prediction in caffe?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation, pycaffe

Does anyone know how can I save the output of predicted class labels of each pixel in FCN semantic segmentation? I would like to see the probability map of the image during inference. The data in which layer should be saved?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As  you can see from the  code in [`infer.py`](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/infer.py#L20) the predicted label is `argmax` of `'score'` layer.

```
out = net.blobs['score'].data[0].argmax(axis=0)
```

The `'score'` is the [input to `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` layer](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn32s/train.prototxt#L520-L530) during training.  Hence, to get class probabilities from `'score'` you need to add `"Softmax"` on top of `'score'`:

```
e_s = np.exp(net.blobs['score'].data[0])
prob = e_s / e_s.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. I could see the probabilities; however, all are same for each pixel. and the output is all zero (a black image).

Comment: You might need to [debug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40510706/1714410) your net and see what went wrong.