# Gradient vanishes when using batch normalization in caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent, batch-normalization

all

I run into problems when I use batch normalization in Caffe.
Here is the code I used in train_val.prototxt.

```
layer {
      name: "conv1"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "conv0"
      top: "conv1"
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
        decay_mult: 1
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 0
        decay_mult: 0
      }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 32
        pad: 1
        kernel_size: 3
        weight_filler {
          type: "gaussian"
          std: 0.0589
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 0
        }
        engine: CUDNN
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "bnorm1"
      type: "BatchNorm"
      bottom: "conv1"
      top: "conv1"
      batch_norm_param {
        use_global_stats: false
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "scale1"
      type: "Scale"
      bottom: "conv1"
      top: "conv1"
      scale_param {
        bias_term: true
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "relu1"
      type: "ReLU"
      bottom: "conv1"
      top: "conv1"
    }

layer {
  name: "conv16"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv16"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
```

However, the training is not converging. By removing BN layers (batchnorm + scale), the training can converge. So I started to compare the log files with or without the BN layers. Here are the log files with debug_info = true:

With BN:

```
I0804 10:22:42.074671  8318 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer loadtestdata, top blob data data: 0.368457
I0804 10:22:42.074757  8318 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer loadtestdata, top blob label data: 0.514496
I0804 10:22:42.076117  8318 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer conv0, top blob conv0 data: 0.115678
I0804 10:22:42.076200  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer conv0, param blob 0 data: 0.0455077
I0804 10:22:42.076273  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer conv0, param blob 1 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.076539  8318 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer relu0, top blob conv0 data: 0.0446758
I0804 10:22:42.078435  8318 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer conv1, top blob conv1 data: 0.0675479
I0804 10:22:42.078516  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer conv1, param blob 0 data: 0.0470226
I0804 10:22:42.078589  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer conv1, param blob 1 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.079108  8318 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer bnorm1, top blob conv1 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.079197  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer bnorm1, param blob 0 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.079270  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer bnorm1, param blob 1 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.079350  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer bnorm1, param blob 2 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.079421  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer bnorm1, param blob 3 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.079505  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer bnorm1, param blob 4 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.080267  8318 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer scale1, top blob conv1 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.080345  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer scale1, param blob 0 data: 1
I0804 10:22:42.080418  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer scale1, param blob 1 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.080651  8318 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer relu1, top blob conv1 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.082074  8318 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer conv16, top blob conv16 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.082154  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer conv16, param blob 0 data: 0.0485365
I0804 10:22:42.082226  8318 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer conv16, param blob 1 data: 0
I0804 10:22:42.082675  8318 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer loss, top blob loss data: 42.0327
```

Without BN:

```
I0803 17:01:29.700850 30274 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer loadtestdata, top blob data data: 0.320584
I0803 17:01:29.700920 30274 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer loadtestdata, top blob label data: 0.236383
I0803 17:01:29.701556 30274 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer conv0, top blob conv0 data: 0.106141
I0803 17:01:29.701633 30274 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer conv0, param blob 0 data: 0.0467062
I0803 17:01:29.701692 30274 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer conv0, param blob 1 data: 0
I0803 17:01:29.701835 30274 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer relu0, top blob conv0 data: 0.0547961
I0803 17:01:29.702193 30274 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer conv1, top blob conv1 data: 0.0716117
I0803 17:01:29.702267 30274 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer conv1, param blob 0 data: 0.0473551
I0803 17:01:29.702327 30274 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer conv1, param blob 1 data: 0
I0803 17:01:29.702425 30274 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer relu1, top blob conv1 data: 0.0318472
I0803 17:01:29.702781 30274 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer conv16, top blob conv16 data: 0.0403702
I0803 17:01:29.702847 30274 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer conv16, param blob 0 data: 0.0474007
I0803 17:01:29.702908 30274 net.cpp:650]     [Forward] Layer conv16, param blob 1 data: 0
I0803 17:01:29.703228 30274 net.cpp:638]     [Forward] Layer loss, top blob loss data: 11.2245
```

it is strange that in forward, every layer starting with batchnorm gives 0!!!
Also it worth mentioned that Relu (in-place layer) have only 4 lines, but batchnorm and scale (supposed to be also in-place layers) have 6 and 3 lines in log file. Do you know what's the problem.

Comment: what version of caffe are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with your `"BatchNorm"` layer, but it is **very odd**:
According to your debug log, your `"BatchNorm"` layer has **5** (!) internal param blobs (0..4). Looking at the source code of [`batch_norm_layer.cpp`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/batch_norm_layer.cpp#L25) there should be only **3** internal param blobs:

> ```
> this->blobs_.resize(3);
> ```

I suggest you make sure the implementation of `"BatchNorm"` you are using is not bugous.

---

About the debug log, you can [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40511421/1714410) more about how to interpret it.
To address your question

> "Relu [...] have only 4 lines, but batchnorm and scale [...] have 6 and 3 lines in log file"

Note that each layer has one line for `"top blob ... data"` - reporting the L2 norm of the output blob.
Additionally, each layer has an extra line for each of its **internal** weights.
`"ReLU"` layer has no internal parameters, and thus no prints of `"param blob [...] data"` for this layer. `"Convolution"` layer has two internal params (kernels and bias), thus an extra two lines for blob 0 and blob 1.