# training loss is nan in keras LSTM

Tags: keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I have tun this code in google colab with GPU to create a multilayer LSTM. It is for time series prediction.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, LSTM, BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import SGD
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 50, activation = 'relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape= 
(1,len(FeaturesDataFrame.columns))))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(3, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))
opt = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, clipvalue=5.0)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt)
```

Note that I have used used the gradient-clipping. But still, when I train this model, it return nan as the training loss:

```
history = model.fit(X_t_reshaped, train_labels, epochs=20, batch_size=96, verbose=2)
```

This is the result

> ```
> Epoch 1/20
> 316/316 - 2s - loss: nan 
> Epoch 2/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan 
> Epoch 3/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 4/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 5/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 6/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 7/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan 
> Epoch 8/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan 
> Epoch 9/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan 
> Epoch 10/20 
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 11/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 12/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 13/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 14/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 15/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan 
> Epoch 16/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 17/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 18/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 19/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> Epoch 20/20
> 316/316 - 1s - loss: nan
> ```

Comment: Try a much much lower learning rate like 1e-4 or 1e-5, and see if it helps. If so, you can try tweaking LR and the other parameters to see if you can avoid a blowup.

Comment: @HoOman  Why are you using ReLU and did you scale the inputs somehow?

Comment: @MustafaAydın I have seen this activation is prevalent. Do you have any recommendation for time-series forecasting application?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm more familiar with working with PyTorch than Keras. However there are still a couple of things I would recommend doing:

1. Check your data. Ensure that there are no missing or null values in the data that you pass into your model. This is is the most likely culprit. A single null value will cause the loss to be NaN.
2. You could try lowering the learning rate (0.001 or something even smaller) and/or removing gradient clipping. I've actually had gradient contributing be the cause of NaN loss before.
3. Try scaling your data (though unscaled data will usually cause infinite losses rather than NaN loses). Use StandardScaler or one of the other scalers in sklearn.

If all that fails then I'd try to just pass some very simple dummy data into the model and see if the problem persists. Then you will know if it is a code problem or a data problem. Hope this helps and feel free to ask questions if you have them.

Comment: Thank you. It was due to presence of Nan values in training data

Comment: StandardScaler fixed it for me! Cant thank you enough.

Comment: Nan values in training data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to NANs or NAs, check if any of your input and output vectors are not all zeros.

Comment: This is already part of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is a very common problem with LSTM.

1. First things first, check if your input has nan or np.inf values. usually, this is not the case, but make sure these are not present.
2. The most probable reason is that you are using relu as an activation function. LSTM's or RNN in general for that matter, don't work well with relu. Read here for further explanation: [Problems of relu](https://analyticsindiamag.com/can-relu-cause-exploding-gradients-if-applied-to-solve-vanishing-gradients/).
3. So the solution for the exploding gradient problem you are encountering can be switching to tanh from relu, which is the default in LSTM's.
4. You can also try reducing the learning rate which minimizes the exploding gradients.
5. One last thing you can also do if you are bent on using relu, is using clipping_values, so that the gradients do not explode while backpropagation (reduce the value of clipvalue in your case). You can also try using dropout, but it will not be very helpful compared to the other suggestions.
6. If none of this work, try reading this: [More explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962226/common-causes-of-nans-during-training-of-neural-networks)

Hope this helps and best of luck :)